# In NetBeans 11, how do I add a Bean from a Maven dependency to the Pallet?

Tags: maven, netbeans, javabeans, netbeans-11

Short version of the question: In NetBeans 11.0, how do I add a Bean from a Maven dependency to the Pallet?

I'm building a Java program using the Maven setup in NetBeans that will need to display SVG content. I've settled on Apache Batik for that and added it to my Dependencies.

Batik supplies a JSVGCanvas bean (possibly others too).
I want design the UI using the Design View and drag my components in. It looks like I have to first add the JSVGCanvas bean to the palette. I brought up Tools->Pallet->Swing/AWT Components, and went through the Add from Jar/Library/Project options. None of them are designed to work for a dependency.

I was able to get the bean in by added from Jar and navigating down from /.m2/repository/.... but this seems wrong.
When someone else gets the code from my source repo, they won't have the beans for this program available. Also, the bean shows up for all of my NetBeans projects, not just the one that uses Batik.

I also see that I can navigate down through the project to the class and there is a context menu item that offers to add the item to the pallet, but it gives an error message telling me to go through the Tools menu as described above.

What is the correct way of doing this, or is there no correct way?